# MS Access SQL query - Count records until value is met

Tags: sql, ms-access

---

**I have an Access query (qr1) that returns the following data:**

| dateField | stringField1 | stringField2 | booleanField |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/09/20 17:15 | John | Nick | 0 |
| 12/09/20 17:00 | John | Mary | -1 |
| 13/09/20 17:30 | Ann | John | 0 |
| 13/09/20 19:30 | Kate | Alan | 0 |
| 19/09/20 19:30 | Ann | Missy | 0 |
| 20/09/20 17:15 | Jim | George | 0 |
| 20/09/20 19:30 | John | Nick | 0 |
| 27/09/20 15:00 | John | Mary | -1 |
| 27/09/20 17:00 | Ann | John | -1 |
| 27/09/20 19:30 | Kate | Alan | 0 |
| 28/09/20 18:30 | Ann | Missy | -1 |
| 03/10/20 18:30 | Jim | George | -1 |
| 04/10/20 15:00 | John | Nick | 0 |
| 04/10/20 17:15 | John | Mary | 0 |
| 04/10/20 20:45 | Ann | John | 0 |
| 05/10/20 18:30 | Kate | Alan | 0 |
| 17/10/20 15:00 | Jim | George | 0 |
| 17/10/20 17:15 | John | Nick | 0 |
| 18/10/20 15:00 | John | Mary | -1 |
| 18/10/20 17:15 | Ann | John | 0 |

**Notes:**

- The string data may by repetitive or not.
- The date data are stored as string. I use a function to convert it as date.

```
Public Function STR2TIME(sTime As String) As Date
Dim arr() As String
    sTime = Replace(sTime, ".", "/")
    arr = Split(sTime, "  ")
    STR2TIME = DateValue(Format(arr(0), "dd/mm/yyyy")) + TimeValue(arr(1))
End Function
```

- qr1 is ORDERED BY STR2TIME(dateField) ASC

---

**Now I need to run an extra query that will do the following:**

- add an extra column where:
- counts records until yes (-1) on
  booleanField
- after this, starts over counting by 1

**In this case the output should look like this:**

| dateField | stringField1 | stringField2 | booleanField | countField |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/09/20 17:15 | John | Nick | 0 | 1 |
| 12/09/20 17:00 | John | Mary | -1 | 2 |
| 13/09/20 17:30 | Ann | John | 0 | 1 |
| 13/09/20 19:30 | Kate | Alan | 0 | 2 |
| 19/09/20 19:30 | Ann | Missy | 0 | 3 |
| 20/09/20 17:15 | Jim | George | 0 | 4 |
| 20/09/20 19:30 | John | Nick | 0 | 5 |
| 27/09/20 15:00 | John | Mary | -1 | 6 |
| 27/09/20 17:00 | Ann | John | -1 | 1 |
| 27/09/20 19:30 | Kate | Alan | 0 | 1 |
| 28/09/20 18:30 | Ann | Missy | -1 | 2 |
| 03/10/20 18:30 | Jim | George | -1 | 1 |
| 04/10/20 15:00 | John | Nick | 0 | 1 |
| 04/10/20 17:15 | John | Mary | 0 | 2 |
| 04/10/20 20:45 | Ann | John | 0 | 3 |
| 05/10/20 18:30 | Kate | Alan | 0 | 4 |
| 17/10/20 15:00 | Jim | George | 0 | 5 |
| 17/10/20 17:15 | John | Nick | 0 | 6 |
| 18/10/20 15:00 | John | Mary | -1 | 7 |
| 18/10/20 17:15 | Ann | John | 0 | 1 |

---

**Problem**

I have tried many things all giving wrong numeric results.

Finally I thought that *counting the zeros from the current date till the previous* (biggest and smaller than the current), would do the trick:

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM qr1 tt 
             WHERE booleanField = 0
             AND STR2TIME(tt.dateField) >= (SELECT TOP 1 dateField
                                           FROM qr1
                                           WHERE booleanField = -1
                                           AND STR2TIME(dateField) < STR2TIME(t.dateField)
                                           ORDER BY STR2TIME(dateField) DESC
                                          )
             AND STR2TIME(tt.dateField) <= STR2TIME(t.dateField)
            ) AS CountMatches
FROM qr1 t;
```

but still gives me wrong numeric results on countField:

| countField |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 13 |

**What am I doing wrong? I can't get it. How to get the desired result?**

---

### **EDIT:**

**I'm posting the final code, based on @Gordon Linoff 's and @Gustav 's answers, slightly simplified.**

Explanation of changes:

- I got rid of the conversion-function in this step. Instead of converting 7 times * every single record, I convert only once in the first query and here the values are ready to compare.
- I omitted checking the zeros as it was not necessary.
- I added NZ function to get values when the inner subquery returns NULL. That is when there isn't any yes with smaller date to count from (first records usually).
- The only problem left, was that with NZ I got values 1 less than what I needed, so I added -1 to the dateField to count 1 more.

**Here is the code:**

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qr2 tt 
             WHERE tt.dateField <= t.dateField
             AND tt.dateField > NZ((SELECT TOP 1 dateField FROM qr2 
                                    WHERE booleanField = True
                                    AND dateField < t.dateField
                                    ORDER BY dateField DESC
                                    ), tt.dateField - 1) 
            ) AS CountMatches
FROM qr2 AS t;
```

Comment: MS Access is just the wrong database for this type of data manipulation.  My suggestion is that you upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable, though a little convoluted:

```sql
Select 
    qr1.dateField, 
    qr1.stringField1, 
    qr1.stringField2, 
    qr1.booleanField, 

        (Select Count(*) From qr1 As t1 
        Where 
            (t1.booleanfield = true And t1.dateField = qr1.dateField) 
            Or
            (t1.booleanfield = false And t1.dateField <= qr1.dateField And 
            t1.dateField >= Nz(
                (Select Top 1 dateField From qr1 As t 
                Where t.dateField < qr1.dateField And t.booleanField = True 
                Order By t.dateField Desc), 
                t1.dateField ))) As countField

From 
    qr1;
```

Output:

[image]

You string converter can be replaced by this expression:

```
TrueDate = CDate(Replace(TextDotDate, ".", "/"))
```

This you should apply at a much earlier state, like in `qr1`.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I will apply the conversion earlier. Although I will not run this query often, it's completely wasted to use the conversion-function so many times in this query.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is:

```
         AND STR2TIME(tt.dateField) >= (SELECT TOP 1 dateField
```

This should be:

```
         AND STR2TIME(tt.dateField) >= (SELECT TOP 1 STR2TIME(dateFielda)
```

Second, you have:

```
WHERE booleanField = 0
```

But I don't think this filter is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. This was really obvious indeed. I'm accepting @Gustav's answer though because it was more complete. e.g. it also includes the case when booleanField is True for the first time so the "previous" value is Null.